Google Storage Transfer Service Error on copy ADLS files
I am running a Google Transfer Job to copy files from ADLS to GCS.
Seems when a specific file in ADLS is being written or updated, the storage transfer job fails for that specific file.
Error The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
I assumed that the job would pick up the last version of the files if its currently being overwritten or leave the files for that job instance and pick up next time.
Any idea on how to resolve this issue?


Error The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.

According to this MS-Document, Blob service operations support the use of conditional headers.,
The above error occurs when the source file is being updated or written while the transfer job is running. The job will not pick up the last version of the file if it is currently being overwritten. Instead, it will try to transfer the file as it is at the moment of the transfer.
If files are updating or modifying in the blob storage , please exclude those files while transferring in Storage Transfer Service.
You can follow this Document by Vikas Kumawat, This will give you info step by step to transfer from ADLS to GCP.

You can also gcloud cli to exclude files by using below command.
Command:
gcloud transfer jobs create  <SOURCE> <DESTINATION> --exclude-prefixes "file is updating"

References:
Create transfers | Cloud Storage Transfer Service Documentation | Google Cloud
